# Rails: How to update multiple models together, with proper rollback (kind of manual nested attributes)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I (for various reasons) have decided not to use `nested_attributes`. Here is my current controller:

```
def update

    # Update snippet
    @snippet.update(snippet_params)

    # Update hotspot
    @snippet.hotspot.update(hotspot_params)

    # Update text
    @snippet.text.update(medium_params_with(:text))

    # Update audio
    if params[:audio] {
      @snippet.audio.destroy
      @snippet.media << Audio.new(medium_params_with(:audio))
    }

    respond_to do |format|
      if success = true #fix this up
        format.html { redirect_to @project, notice: 'Snippet was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @snippet }
      else
        format.html { redirect_to @project, warning: 'Highlight was not updated.' }
        format.json { render json: @snippet.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
end
```

This is more or less OK if nothing goes wrong.

How do I wrap this into something like:

```
try {
  update everything
} else {
  undo any changes I made while trying to update everything
}

if success {
  etc
} else {
  etc
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If what you are changing are ActiveRecord models using a SQL database then http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Transactions/ClassMethods.html might provide exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks, I think that's what I'm looking for, but could you please explain this sentence (from those docs)? _Exceptions will force a ROLLBACK that returns the database to the state before the transaction began. Be aware, though, that the objects will not have their instance data returned to their pre-transactional state._

Comment: A rollback will prevent the changes you were saving from being persisted to the database but you will still have models with unsaved changes in memory (e.g. your `@snippet.changed` would show you unsaved changes).  Depending on how you use those models you could unintentionally attempt to save this set of changes again which might be a problem.

Comment: You may not need to but if you do: http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/AttributeMethods/Dirty/reload is one option.

Answer (score 2):

Following @Jonah's answer, I wrapped the DB changes in `ActiveRecord::Base.transaction`:

```
def update

  success = ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do

    # Update snippet
    @snippet.update(snippet_params)

    # Update text
    @snippet.text.update(medium_params_with(:text))

    # Update audio
    if params[:audio]
      @snippet.audio.destroy
      @snippet.media << Audio.new(medium_params_with(:audio))
    end
  end

  respond_to do |format|
    if success
      format.html { redirect_to @project, notice: 'Snippet was successfully updated.' }
      format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @snippet }
    else
      format.html { redirect_to @project, warning: 'Highlight was not updated.' }
      format.json { render json: @snippet.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```